# How am i able to retrieve specific users data using StreamBuilder?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

**1) This is the view team/view roster screen.    https://i.stack.imgur.com/95uEV.jpg**

```
  class ViewTeamScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/view-team';
  const ViewTeamScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<List<User>>.value(
      value: DBService().getAllUsers,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: TeamList()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**2) This is the team list code that displays all user data on the ViewTeamScreen and returns a TeamTile widget i created.**

```
class TeamList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TeamListState createState() => _TeamListState();
}

class _TeamListState extends State<TeamList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final users = Provider.of<List<User>>(context) ?? [];
    //print(users);

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: users.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return TeamTile(
          user: users[index],
        );
      },
    );
```

**3) This is the TeamTile, which returns ListViewBuilder for a team member once they sign up to the app.**

```
class TeamTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final User user;
  TeamTile({this.user});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 6, 20, 0),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            radius: 30.0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
          ),
          title: Text(
            '${user.firstName}'
            " "
            '${user.lastName}', //how do i make the first letter of name always CAPS?
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23, letterSpacing: 1.0),
          ),
          trailing: Text(user.email),
          subtitle: Text('+44 0000 000 000'),
          onTap: () async {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => TeamDetailScreen(),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
```

**4) This is the team detail screen, once the user taps on the ListTile in the ViewTeamScreen, this page will apear. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHDu3.jpg**

```
class TeamDetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Employee Contact Info'),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<User>(
        stream: DBService(uid: user.uid).usersData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            User userData = snapshot.data;

            return Column(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Name: ${userData.firstName}'
                  " "
                  '${userData.lastName}\n'
                  'Email: ${userData.email}',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: (20)),
                ),
              )),
            ]);
          } else {
            return Loading();
```

Comment: May you please clarify more on the issue, I am still a bit confused on what you're trying to accomplish or what the issue is.

Comment: @Unbreachable Hi yes, the problem im facing is that once I click the ListTile in this picture  https://imgur.com/a/k63lQrt , i want to be able to show that users details on the screen but I can only access that logged in users name, email etc.. I don't know how much more i can expand on that sorry.

Comment: Thank you, may you please post the rest of the code? The "roster page", you are going to need to pass each index from the "roster page" to the "detail screen"

Comment: @Unbreachable Hi there of course, sorry about that I've just updated the code and included all the relevant files so maybe you can understand the structure of the app. Thank You any help would be greatly appreciated! - i have been stuck on this for hours

Comment: Just try to add user data into stream once you tap the list tile..

Comment: @proversion could u perhaps give an example pls?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to exclude *StreamProvider* and just use *StreamBuilder*. This concept is easy to understand, as all we are doing is passing the *widget.index* down to other Widgets as arguments.

#### 1

```
class ViewTeamScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<User>>(
        stream: DBService().getAllUsers,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {

          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<User> userData = snapshot.data;

            return Scaffold(body: TeamList(myData: userData));
          } else {
            return Loading();
          }
        });
  }
}
```

#### 2

```
 class TeamList extends StatefulWidget {
      final List<User> myData;

      TeamList({this.myData});

      @override
      _TeamListState createState() => _TeamListState();
    }

    class _TeamListState extends State<TeamList> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: widget.myData.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return TeamTile(
              usersInfo: widget.myData[index],
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

#### 3

```
class TeamTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final User usersInfo;
  TeamTile({this.usersInfo});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 6, 20, 0),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            radius: 30.0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.brown,
          ),
          title: Text(
            '${usersInfo.firstName}'
            " "
            '${usersInfo.lastName}', //how do i make the first letter of name always CAPS?
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23, letterSpacing: 1.0),
          ),
          trailing: Text(usersInfo.email),
          subtitle: Text('+44 0000 000 000'),
          onTap: () async {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => TeamDetailScreen(myDetails: usersInfo),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### 4

```
 class TeamDetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      final User myDetails;
      TeamDetailScreen({this.myDetails});

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          body: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
                child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                'Name: ${myDetails.firstName}'
                " "
                '${myDetails.lastName}\n'
                'Email: ${myDetails.email}',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: (20)),
              ),
            )),
          ]),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: thank you sooo much @Unreachable this worked like a charm i did not realise you could pass down data like that via the streambuilder and overcomplicated it with the streamprovider this makes so much more sense now !! i appreciate ur help could not get my head around this without your help :D